# Keep ssh session alive after connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I want to ssh into a remote box, and call `mysql` inside and start a connection. I can retrieve the password and login to mysql so I wanted to make a script to do this in one go:

```
passwd=$(get_password)
ssh $TEST_BOX << EOT
mysql -u $USER -p$passwd -h $FOO --port=$BAR
EOT
```

This ssh's into the box, runs the command to run and login to mysql, but it doesn't persist the connection and just drops. Is there some flag I'm missing in the ssh man page to keep this alive so I can actually make queries to the db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't redirect into ssh. Try

```
ssh -t $hostname 'mysql -u ....'
```